# Why do two MySQL dates in 1582 appear to be the same but comparison result is false?

Tags: mysql, sql, calendar, gregorian-calendar, sql-date-functions

I know that Gregorian calendar started on Oct 15th 1582, and during the transition from Julian calendar, 10 days had been dropped.

When I'm doing this query:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('1582-10-05', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

I'm getting this result:

```
1582-10-15 (the 10 days difference).
```

But when I'm trying to match between such dates I'm getting the original date (Oct 5th and not 15th).

For example:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('1582-10-05', '%Y-%m-%d') = STR_TO_DATE('1582-10-15', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

I'm getting a false response, although you would have expected to get a true since Oct 5th actually count as Oct 15th, as we saw in the first example.

Anyone can explain what's going on here?

Comment: Are you running the command in MySQL, or something else? MySQL uses a proleptic calendar so it should just show whatever value you enter into it (it does on my machine, and it does on rextester). On sqlfiddle it returns the 15th - but i can't help wondering if that isn't down to some internal processing not related to MySQL. Incidentally, in the UK the Gregorian calendar was adopted in September 1752, and in Russia I think it was at the October (so actually November) revolution

Comment: @Strawberry, I'm using MySQL on Amazon's EC2 instance. I'm connecting through DataGrip (not that's important). I tried it on Redshift as well and got the same results. On rextester I'm not seeing the 10 days difference.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-calendar.html -- `SELECT TO_DAYS('1582-10-15') - TO_DAYS('1582-10-04');` gives me 11; should be 1?

Answer (score 12):

On [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) it is stated that, `TO_DAYS` and `FROM_DAYS` functions must be called cautiously because of the transformation you noticed. Additionally, when I inspect the [source codes](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/71f48ab393bce80a59e5a2e498cd1f46f6b43f9a/include/my_time.h) of MySQL, I realized that `STR_TO_DATE` uses similar methodology with these functions. As I understand, cutover dates are completely unsafe to store or apply operations. Documentation says; `"Dates during a cutover are nonexistent."`, too.

Also for the inconsistency between different servers I may have an explanation. I have 2 different machines which have MySQL installed in Istanbul, Turkey and Frankfurt, Germany. They have same setup **excluding localisation settings**. First one shows 1, the other one shows 11 for the date substraction query. It means (in my humble opinion) there is unexplained sections about calendar cutover & localisation on official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the following results:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('1582-10-05', '%Y-%m-%d');
# Result #1: 1582-10-15

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('1582-10-05', '%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y-%m-%d');
# Result #2: 1582-10-05

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('1582-10-15', '%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y-%m-%d');
# Result #3: 1582-10-15
```

[SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71a49/27).

These indicate the problem lies in the way the `1582-10-05` date is displayed rather than how it is stored. Result #2 shows that if the [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#idm139924006609104) function is used instead to *explicitly* convert the date into the same string format then the input date is displayed. This also explains why the comparison query in the question returns false: Behind the scenes, the two stored dates *are* different.

As you've discovered, this quirk occurs for all dates between `1582-10-05` and `1582-10-14` inclusive, i.e. [the range of dates that don't really exist](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-calendar.html): The implicit conversion to text for all of these gives a date 10 days after. So if for some reason there is a need to display dates in this range *(perhaps questionable)*, a simple workaround is to always use the `DATE_FORMAT` function.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just to make sure I understand your point. You claim that there is a bug in mySql which cause it to show `1582-10-05` as `1582-10-15` (on STR_TO_DATE function) but behind the scenes it's still `1582-10-05`?

Comment: Pretty much, although I'd hesitate to use the word "bug" as their documentation does mention that the dates in the mentioned range are (a) non-existent in the calendar used by MySQL and (b) unsafe to use (as per Tuğca Eker's answer).

Comment: Another example is this:
`SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('1582-10-04', '%Y-%m-
%d'), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL 1 DAY)` which will give you a result of `1582-10-16` . Hence `1582-10-05` was actually treated just like `1582-10-15`

Comment: Looks like this has the same explanation: The dates are correct behind the scenes so the calculated answer is 6th October but MySQL is displaying this as 16th October. Try `DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('1582-10-04', '%Y-%m- %d'), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y-%m-%d')` and you'll see that it results in 6th October.

Comment: Write a bug report asking for a clarification in the documentation.  Use the above comments as a basis.  https://bugs.mysql.com/